# extra space above table with <br> tag in tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE text editor. It has a feature of inserting table inside the editor. The problem is, when I display the table after the user clicks submit, there are some blank spaces (too many `<br>`) above the table, which don't seem to go away. This doesn't happen when I type in normal text, etc but only with tables.

Comment: Please post more information / code / examples (jsfiddle).

Comment: some code would come in handy don't you think?

Comment: @Mees Kluivers https://jsfiddle.net/gh123hbp/

Comment: If I add a table in TinyMCE there are no `<br>`s added at all.  Are you sure this is a TinyMCE issue or is this an issue when you save the content?  If TinyMCE looks correct but the data is wrong after saving look at the Laravel code that is saving the content.

Comment: @Michael Fromin this issue occured when save data in database and just when adding table while in other case not happen

Comment: @Michael Fromin I think my laravel code does n't have bug

Comment: Well if the data is correct when it leaves TinyMCE and its wrong later the issue is not in TinyMCE.

Comment: @Michael Fromin OK